# shell array loop stops after 1

Tags: shell, loops

I'm at a loss why this loop stops after the first item. Can someone point me in a direction? Thanks!

```
#! /bin/sh

colors[0]="teal"
colors[1]="purple"
colors[2]="pink"
colors[3]="red"
colors[4]="green"
colors[5]="darkblue"
colors[6]="skyblue"

for color in ${colors}
do
    echo $color
done
```

Comment: /bin/sh does not support arrays.  Change your shebang to "#!/bin/bash" if you intend your script to be running under bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to the following:

```
for color in "${colors[@]}"
do
    echo $color
done
```

Removing the quotes would work for your example, but not if there were any spaces in a single color (for example `"sky blue"`).

Comment: Thanks FJ. I'm curious what's the difference between using [@] and [*]?

Comment: @RedLabor Without quotes there is no difference, `[*]` with quotes will give you the entire array on a separate line, `[@]` with quotes will still give you each color on a separate line.

Comment: @RedLabor, this is particularly important if any of the colors has a space, such as `colors[7]="light blue"` -- then `"${colors[@]}"` is the only way to properly iterate.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many ways to do it is to use `for` loop. Additional info here is how to get the size of the array.

```
#Get the size of the array
nColors=${#colors[*]}
for (( Idx = 0; Idx < $nColors; ++Idx  )); do
    echo "${colors[$Idx]}"
done
```